# PostgreSQL Foreign Key syntax

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have 2 tables as you will see in my PosgreSQL code below. The first table students has 2 columns, one for `student_name` and the other `student_id` which is the Primary Key.

In my second table called tests, this has 4 columns, one for  `subject_id`, one for the `subject_name`, then one for a student with the highest score in a subject which is `highestStudent_id`. am trying to make `highestStudent_id` refer to `student_id` in my students table. This is the code I have below, am not sure if the syntax is correct:

```
CREATE TABLE students ( student_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                 player_name TEXT);

CREATE TABLE tests ( subject_id SERIAL,
                   subject_name,
                   highestStudent_id SERIAL REFERENCES students);
```

is the syntax `highestStudent_id SERIAL REFERENCES students` correct? because i have seen another one like `highestStudent_id  REFERENCES students(student_id))`

What would be the correct way of creating the foreign key in PostgreSQL please?

Comment: Yes the syntax is "correct". However the FK column should **not** be defined as `serial` it should defined as `integer`. `serial` is not a "real" data type, it's a short hand for populating the default value from sequence

Comment: If the FK references a primary key, no columns are needed. If the FK references an alternate key, columns are needed.

Comment: Your foreign key references the table "players". You don't appear to *have* a table named "players".

Comment: @Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall sorry , my mistake i meant highestStudent_id integer REFERENCES students

Answer (score 450, accepted):

Assuming this table:

```
CREATE TABLE students 
( 
  student_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  player_name TEXT
);
```

There are four different ways to define a foreign key (when dealing with a single column PK) and they all lead to the same foreign key constraint:

1. Inline without mentioning the target column:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE tests 
   ( 
      subject_id SERIAL,
      subject_name text,
      highestStudent_id integer REFERENCES students
   );
   ```
2. Inline with mentioning the target column:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE tests 
   ( 
      subject_id SERIAL,
      subject_name text,
      highestStudent_id integer REFERENCES students (student_id)
   );
   ```
3. Out of line inside the `create table`:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE tests 
   ( 
     subject_id SERIAL,
     subject_name text,
     highestStudent_id integer, 
     constraint fk_tests_students
        foreign key (highestStudent_id) 
        REFERENCES students (student_id)
   );
   ```
4. As a separate `alter table` statement:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE tests 
   ( 
     subject_id SERIAL,
     subject_name text,
     highestStudent_id integer
   );

   alter table tests 
       add constraint fk_tests_students
       foreign key (highestStudent_id) 
       REFERENCES students (student_id);
   ```

Which one you prefer is a matter of taste. But you should be consistent in your scripts. The last two statements are the only option if you have foreign keys referencing a PK that consists of more than one column - you can't define the FK "inline" in that case, e.g. `foreign key (a,b) references foo (x,y)`

Only version 3) and 4) will give you the ability to define your own name for the FK constraint if you don't like the system generated ones from Postgres.

---

The `serial` data type is not really a data type. It's just a short hand notation that defines a default value for the column taken from a sequence. So any column *referencing* a column defined as `serial` must be defined using the appropriate base type `integer` (or `bigint` for `bigserial` columns)

Comment: This link (https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-foreign-key/) shows another way to do what you said can only be done with the 'constraint' command in 3 and 4.  Also, what about putting FOREIGN KEY before the FK?  It looks like when we do that, we don't have to declare the variable type?

Comment: For the `alter table` variant, you don't need to specify the constraint name if you don't want to, btw. This works: `ALTER TABLE "FROM_TABLE" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("FROM_COLUMN") REFERENCES "TO_TABLE" ("TO_COLUMN");`

Comment: @Venryx It's always a good idea to specify the constraint name. When you have to drop these constraints through migrations it becomes easier. Without the names it's a nightmare because each server will generate its own name and your migration script may fail.

Answer (score 5):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD FOREIGN KEY(colunm_name) REFERENCES reference_table_name(reference_column_name);
```

Note the column must have already been created.