# In what situation must we define a referencing table in a relationship as a foreign key?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

In this Diagram

[image: Diagram]

the `Enrolls` table (at the top) only has `Courses` defined as a foreign key while in the `Supplies` table (at the bottom), every referenced Primary Key of the original tables is defined as foreign key.

Why is this so? Thank you!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: you should never use the `char()` data type.

Comment: Not sure what your question is. What foreign keys are you missing in the `enrolls` table? It does define `sid` as a foreign key to `students`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, my confusion stems from the Enrolls table not explicitly defining `sid` as a foreign key while `cid` is. As opposed to the Supplies table explicitly writing "foreign key (xid)" for each of the foreign keys. Why is this done? Thanks!

Comment: The `enrolls` table does define `sid` explicitly as a foreign key: `sid char(20) REFERENCES students`  - what's not "explicit" about that? It's just a different syntax that does the same as the one used for `cid`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I see what you are saying. May I ask if it is possible for the Enrolls table to then omit the line `foreign key(cid) reference Courses` and instead put `references Courses` on line 3 where the `cid` is defined? Would this mean the same thing? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that would mean the same thing. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28560619

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both references in `Enrolls` are defined as foreign keys like they should. Only the foreign key on `sid` is written using the "column constraint" syntax, while the one on `cid` is written using the "table constraint" syntax.

The end effect is the same; it doesn't matter which syntax variant you use.